# Extension of $C^r$-differentiable function to open set

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $f:S\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be $C^r$-differentiable at each point $x_0\in S$. Prove that $f$ can be extended to a $C^r$ function $h:A\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $A$ is an open set containing $S$.
>
> ($C^r$-differentiability of $f$ at $x_0\in S$ means that there exists a $C^r$ function $g:U\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ where $U$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ such that $f$ and $g$ agree on $U\cap S$.)

For each point $x_0\in S$, consider the neighborhood $U(x_0)$ as given in the definition of $C^r$-differentiability. Take $A$ to be the union of all $U(x_0)$, so that $A$ is an open set containing $S$.

There exists a $C^{\infty}$ partition of unity $\{\phi_i\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ on $A$ such that for each $i$, the support of $\phi_i$ is contained in some $U(x_i)$.

Now, we know that $h$ has to match $f$ inside $S$. We only need to define $h(x)$ for $x\in A\backslash S$. For each neighborhood $U(x_0)$, we already have the $C_r$ function $g_{x_0}$ defined in $U(x_0)$. The problem is that for points $x\in A\backslash S$ that belong to different $U(x_0)$'s, the values of the corresponding $g$'s might not match. Can we use the partition of unity to help with defining the values $h(x)$ for $x\in A\backslash S$?

Comment: That's exactly what the partition of unity is intended for. Say the support of $\phi_i$ is contained in $U(x_i)$, and call $h_i$ the $C^r$ function on $U(x_i)$ that agrees with $h$ on $S\cap U(x_i)$. Then, what can you do with $\sum \phi_i\cdot h_i$?

Comment: @DanielFischer So I tried to calculate $\sum\phi_i(x)\cdot h_i(x)$ for $x\in S$. We know that $\sum\phi_i(x)=1$. We have that $h_i(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in U(x_i)$ and $h_i(x)=0$ if not. Now for any $x\in S$, I don't really know which $U(x_i)$ contains it. How can I go further?

Comment: That's the nice thing, you don't need to know. For $x \in S$, you have $h_i(x) = f(x)$, or $\phi_i(x) = 0$ (possibly both). So for $x\in S$, $\phi_i(x)\cdot h_i(x) = \phi_i(x)\cdot f(x)$.

Comment: Oh right, because if $x\not\in U(x_i)$ then it is not in the support of $\phi_i$, so $\phi_i(x)=0$.

Comment: Yep. So $\sum \phi_i\cdot h_i$ is an extension of $f$. Assuming that your partition of unity has the family of supports locally finite (as one customarily wants), it is $C^r$. Done.

Comment: Right, I was just looking at the local finiteness condition to show that it's $C^r$. Thanks Daniel!